# IFS has mismatched range sizes - Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

```
=IFs(Summary!L2="October", QUERY(Data!A2:E, "where month(A)+1=10 and E = 'Expense'"), Summary!L2="February", QUERY(Data!A2:E, "where month(A)+1=2 and E = 'Expense'"))
```

Date         Amount     Description Category
23-Oct-2022 ₪6,969.00   F            B  Expense

Hi,
I’m trying to apply this to all months to all months but it keeps returning IFS mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 1. Column count 1. Actual Row count 1, column count 5. Summary!L2 is set to October

If anyone knows how to fix this it would be greatly appreciated (if the sheet is needed I can send the link)

Thanks

Comment: Provide a very simplified dataset with the before and after you wish to see. Right now you have different sized arrays so it’s not clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: If the linked duplicate answers doesn't answer your question, [edit] your question to explain how the answers don't satisfy your question. Note that there's a proper [etiquette](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252252) to dispute a duplicate. If you're having trouble implementing a solution in the duplicate or don't understand a solution provided, ask a new **specific** question **with the part you're having trouble with**.

Comment: For future questions,

Comment: Make sure to add input and expected output as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE/LINK) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a [mre].[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vSaDPB68WFrEUdMDop7xqaQOBeaQ_42Yw2q2FyJv_yk/edit

If you go to the transactions sheet that’s what I’m trying to achieve but when I switch months I want the transactions from different months to display

Comment: If this isn’t enough I can create a new spreadsheet when I get home